# Resque is writing to the development database even when run from a server in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

When I launch my app in production to test it before rolling out to the server, I noticed that one of my database operations which is called by Resque.enqueue(worker) is performed on the WRONG database! development.sqlite3 instead of production.sqlite3.  I'm running both the server and resque with zero configuration files.  There must be some way to run redis or resque in the correct environment.

```
defaults: &defaults
host: localhost
port: 6379
development:
<<: *defaults
test:
<<: *defaults
staging:
<<: *defaults
production:
<<: *defaults
```

This redis config file I found may hold the key, but redis doesn't like it, saying

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
 Reading the configuration file, at line 1
>>> 'defaults: &defaults'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Comment: I filled in the config files according to what I saw here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075874/need-help-configuring-a-redis-backed-library-on-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you start resque worker in the production environment ? You can do it like this,

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

Comment: This was the key.  I also launch with 
`RAILS_ENV=production resque-web config/initializers/resque.rb` 
or things don't seem to work.  Thank you!