# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound for all workers in Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, resque

I'm working with Resque however all my workers are giving me ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound errors. Is there some kind of setup error. I did the relevant part to load the Rails environment. https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-ensure-my-rails-classesenvironment-is-loaded but still I'm getting these errors.

[image: Resque admin panel]

Database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_development
  pool: 19
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: app_test
  pool: 19
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['POSTGRES_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: localhost
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
gem 'rails', '3.2.18'
gem 'pg'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem 'will_paginate', '>= 3.0.2'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'redis'
gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'resque', :require => "resque/server"
# Use unicorn as the web server
#gem 'unicorn'
gem 'puma', '~> 2.8.2'
gem 'rack-timeout' #threaded abort requests that are taking too long...

gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'gritter'
gem 'client_side_validations', :git => 'git://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git', :branch => '3-2-stable'
gem 'strong_parameters', '>= 0.1.4', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/strong_parameters.git'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'foreigner'
gem 'hpricot' 
gem 'roadie'
#gem 'premailer-rails3'
gem 'chronic'
gem 'ransack', :git => 'git://github.com/markysharky70/ransack.git' 
gem 'mini_magick'
#gem 'rmagick'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'imgkit'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'
gem 'right_aws'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'authorize_net', '1.5.2', :git => 'git://github.com/markysharky70/authorize_net'
gem 'detect_timezone_rails'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'wicked'
gem 'heroku-api'
gem 'ar_after_transaction'
gem 'browser'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'auto_strip_attributes', '~> 1.0'
gem 'jquery_datepicker'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'zendesk_api'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'geokit-rails', '~> 2.0.1'
gem 'activerecord-postgres-hstore'
gem 's3_swf_upload', :git => 'git://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin'
gem 'airbrake'

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails3-generators'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'ruby_parser'
  #gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'debugger-ruby_core_source'
  gem 'debugger'
  #gem 'byebug'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  #gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-puma'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.40.0'
  gem 'rubyzip', '~> 1.0'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rubygems-bundler'
  gem 'bullet'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'quiet_assets'  
  gem 'guard-livereload', :require => false
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork', '>= 1.0.0.rc2'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem "timecop"
  gem "flexmock"
  gem "resque_spec"
  gem "show_me_the_cookies"
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate' 
  gem 'rb-inotify', '~> 0.8.8', :require => false
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'webrick', '1.3.1'
end
```

Comment: does your code runs successfully without resque?

Comment: Do you start your worker in the same environment (i.e. development or production) as the web server environment? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12099257/344347).

Comment: @SachinSingh Yes it does.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov I tried `RAILS_ENV=development QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work`. Still didn't work.

Comment: could you show your database.yml and gemfile?

Comment: @kartikluke just see are you able to get your worker working after you do this `POSTGRES_USERNAME=xxx POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxx RAILS_ENV=development QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work ` if yes then you probably know where your problem lies also the error state record not found are you sure the record actually exist in db cheer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the people maintaining the project I found that I'd exported some environment variables of another project globally particularly DATABASE_URL and that led to the problem.